# DB2 - SQL0347W The recursive common table expression \"IINYGBKY.TBNEW\" may contain an infinite loop. SQLSTATE=01605

Tags: db2

```
with tbNew(sts) as (
    select 
      s
    FROM 
      (values(timestamp('${startDate}','00:00:00'))) t(s)
    union all 
    select 
      sts + ${period} SECONDS
    FROM 
    tbNew 
    WHERE 
      sts + ${period} SECONDS < timestamp('${endDate}','23:59:59'))
  ) 
  select 
    sts AS dummy_interval
  FROM 
    tbNew
```

the above query is running find in dbeaver but throwing error in code:

> The recursive common table expression "IINYGBKY.TBNEW" may contain an infinite loop.  SQLSTATE=01605

Not able to find out what I am doing wrong in here.

Comment: **W** at the end of SQLCODE means **W**arning, not error as codes with **N** at the end.

Comment: Add a counter and limit the result in a WHERE condition so the loop won't be infinite

Comment: If `period` happens to be zero or negative then yes, it will iterate for ever.

Comment: Db2 raises a warning because it cant guarantee that the recursion will terminate. A common trick to avoid the warning is to add an iterating variabel and a terminating condition based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your code to something like:

```
with tbNew(sts, n) as (
    select 
      s, 0
    FROM 
      (values(timestamp('${startDate}','00:00:00'))) t(s)
    union all 
    select 
      sts + ${period} SECONDS, n+1
    FROM 
    tbNew 
    WHERE 
      sts + ${period} SECONDS < timestamp('${endDate}','23:59:59'))
      AND n<100000
  ) 
  select 
    sts AS dummy_interval
  FROM 
    tbNew
```

You can for what its worth simplify your base case to:

```
with tbNew(sts, n) as (
    (values(timestamp('${startDate}','00:00:00')), 0)
    union all 
    ...
```